# Reveal hidden location in matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a program that hides/reveals parts of a matrix. It's hard to explain but here is a visual example.

```
1 * * * * 
2 * * * * 
3 * * * * 
4 * * * * 
  1 2 3 4
```

If the user enters 1,4 the star in position 1,4 will be replaced with the value hidden behind it: 0,3 in my array.

```
1 * * * A 
2 * * * * 
3 * * * * 
4 * * * * 
  1 2 3 4
```

So far, I was able to make the code for the first grid that doesn't have any revealed characters. Any hints on how I can get my program to reveal parts entered by user?

Here is my code so far:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= board.length;i++){
System.out.print(i+ " ");
    for(int j = 0; j < board.length;j++){
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
System.out.print("  ");
for(int t=1; t<= board.length;t++){
    System.out.print(t+" ");
}
System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("Enter a pair of undiscovered distinct locations on the board that you want           revealed.");

int userinput1 = keyboard.nextInt();
int userinput2 = keyboard.nextInt();


while(userinput1 > board.length || userinput2 > board.length){
    System.out.println("The location is invalid. It is outside of the board.");

    System.out.println("Re enter your first location:");

    userinput1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    userinput2 = keyboard.nextInt();
}

// here I need to redisplay the board with the location revealed
```

Comment: should i add it? It's pretty long though and this part isn't really the aim of the code so it will be confusing adding the entire thing.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. We are here to answer questions about code, but not to write code for you. It generally works like this: You code something and run into a problem. You paste the **part of the code** that you suspect causes the problem, together with a description of what went wrong. After that someone here will hopefully be able to help you fix your problem.

Comment: why don't you re-initialize the array by putting the exact `row` and `column` index. e.g. `array[userRow-1][userColumn-1]=userValue;`

Comment: @VighaneshGursale How can you say to do that when we don't even know what the code is? I can think of a couple other ways imsocool could be displaying the array.

Comment: I'm having trouble putting the code... Can I just post the java file?

Comment: @VighaneshGursale Having trouble understanding that. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Quincunx Oh didn't know you could have another person edit for you :P I accepted your edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you print the array of stars, (without the labels underneath):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= board.length;i++){
System.out.print(i+ " ");
    for(int j = 0; j < board.length;j++){
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

This code: `System.out.print("* ");`. You use this to print a `*` for each location of the grid that is hidden. If we wanted to print the value at that point, assuming your `board` is a `char[][]` or maybe `String[][]`, all you'd have to do is access that location of the grid. So if we wanted to print the entire grid uncovered, we'd do this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= board.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i +  " "); // try to indent your code properly
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) { // using board[i].length will make it so you don't need a square 2d-array, and it could even be jagged if you wanted.
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); //Note: the quotes are unneeded.
}
```

You want to reveal a specific location in the grid, not the whole thing. So we need a way of determining whether or not to reveal that location. One possibility is to use a `boolean[][]`. That would mean you should do something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= board.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i +  " ");
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        if (isrevealed(i,j)) System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
        else System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I'll leave you to figure out how you want to do the `isrevealed`.

---

There is (at least) one another way of doing this, that also involves using another 2d array. For example, we could have another `char[][]` named `display` that has the same dimensions as `board`, and we could initialize each element as a `*`. Then we'd simply do this every time we want to display the board, whether or not anything is revealed:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= board.length; i++){
    System.out.print(i +  " ");
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(display[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Please note that you should probably wrap this code in a method, since it seems like you will be using it multiple times. Example method:

```
public static void printBoard(char[][] board, boolean[][] is_revealed) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= board.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i +  " ");
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (is_revealed[i][j]) System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            else System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much haven't figured it out yet but I'm I think I'm close to getting it.

Comment: @imsocoolhahahaha You are welcome. In the future, try to make your questions look similar to what it is like now. Also note that it is better if you show what you attempted for actually doing what you asked for, even if that doesn't work.

Comment: I have another question too. I got one letter to be revealed but what if I want two?

Comment: @imsocoolhahahaha You may have used a simple boolean variable. We want to have a boolean variable for each possible location, so we'd need a `boolean[][]` of the appropriate size.

Comment: Nevermind that was a dumb question. Just added an else if with another boolean for the second set of values. That was embarrassing....

Comment: ....And I've got to bug you with another question.... Any position value in the fourth row crashes my program. Even if I try to reveal all of the matrix with this seems to happen. What do you think is the cause of this?

Comment: @imsocoolhahahaha Are you plugging the user-input directly into the array? If so, you might be getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You might have meant to subtract `1` from the input before doing so.